# how to disable another event when done click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 `li` element and I want when hover (`mouseenter`,`mouseleave`) everyone of them change background-color for everyone that choose.

I do it this work with this code :

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() 
        {
            $('#center-group').children().on('mouseenter',function(){
                    $(this).children('.topmenu').children('.r-part').css('background-color','#810000');
                    $(this).children('.topmenu').children('.r-part').children('.r-part-bot').css('background-color','#980000');
            });
            $('#center-group').children().on('mouseleave',function(){
                    $(this).children('.topmenu').children('.r-part').css('background-color','#404040');
                    $(this).children('.topmenu').children('.r-part').children('.r-part-bot').css('background-color','#4c4c4c');
            });
        });
        </script>
```

now I want when select (`click event`) everyone of li change background-color and don't work top event !!! how do it ??? please guide me....

Comment: Why are you binding two events to same objects ?

Comment: `$('#center-group').children().on('mouseenter',function(){` this should be `$('#center-group').children().on('mouseleave',function(){` for the second one.

Comment: sorry I type this mistake and edit it now answer me please

Comment: Can you copy paste your html as well?

Comment: one thing u can do is to stop event propagation and u can off an event using jquery .off() function (http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: my friend this is my problem : I done click event and change background-color now when leave this element active mouseleave event and change background-color element. I want when click on element mouseleave element don't working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this correct code:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','#center-group li',function(){
                    $(this).children('.topmenu').children('.r-part').css('background-color','#810000').children('.r-part-bot').css('background-color','#980000');;
            });
            $(document).on('mouseleave','#center-group li',function(){
                    $('#center-group').children().not('.selected').children('.topmenu').children('.r-part').css('background-color','#404040').children('.r-part-bot').css('background-color','#4c4c4c');
            });

            $(document).on('click','#center-group li',function(){
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
                $('#center-group').children('.selected').children('.topmenu').children('.r-part').css('background-color','#810000').children('.r-part-bot').css('background-color','#980000');
                $('#center-group').children().not('.selected').children('.topmenu').children('.r-part').css('background-color','#404040').children('.r-part-bot').css('background-color','#4c4c4c');
```